# How to get JSON obeject from view using REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I using django Rest Framework and i want to get JSON that build by Rest Framework and using search. So i need to use **empidlong** for calling outside JSON request.

e.g. `http://localhost:8000/abc/?search=12`

if u surf above url u will get

**This is making from Rest API when call above URL**

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "company": "ABC",
        "plate_no": "1234",
        "project_code": "ABC1234",
        "empidlong": "123456",

    },
]
```

**This is my code views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from .models import getData
from .serializers import CarSerializer
import requests

#def res(requests):
#    res = pd.DataFrame(list(getData.objects.all().values()))

class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    #filter_class = getDataFilter
    #filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
    #queryset = getData.objects.all()
    #serializer_class = CarSerializer
    queryset = getData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    __basic_fields = ('plate_no',)
    search_fields = __basic_fields

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        #serializer = ProfileSerializer(instance=instance)

        serializer = CarSerializer(instance=instance)
        data = serializer.data
        for a in data:
            empid= a['empidlong']
            requests.get('http://192.168.10.32/BASIC%20DATA/GetEmployees/'+empid +'/Y')

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = getData.objects.all()
        emp = self.request.query_params.get('emp', None)

        if emp is not None:
            queryset =  queryset.filter(empidlong=emp)

        return queryset
```

The Problem is while i ran this code             **requests.get('http://192.168.10.32/GetEmployees/'+empid)**

This URL Request wont working(not send get request)

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: No but sometimes change code, It will return RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: What is the `status code` of the ***external request***?

Comment: I was using wireshark and found that no requesting packet to 192.168.10.32

Comment: you need to include `Employees` end-point or ModelViewset which actually serve that and also the `urls` end-point.  `CarViewset` surely not serving `employees` result.

Comment: yes  problem solved using this in   get_queryset `queryset = getData.objects.all()
        queryset2 = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = CarSerializer(queryset2, many=True)`

Comment: is this url is working please check with browser request > http://192.168.10.32/BASIC DATA/GetEmployees/'+empid +'/Y'

Answer (score -1):

Hello in the url your are not specifying the method you want to use. Try this for expample

```
requests.GET.get('http://192.168.10.32/BASIC%20DATA/GetEmployees/'+empid +'/Y')
```

Comment: You may be misunderstood between the **Django `request`** object and **Python `request` library**

Comment: Apologies for that. Kindly undo the flag thing, I will highly appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: SO not allowing me to do so since you haven't ***modified the answer***.